# How to use Go's time.Tick?

Tags: timer, go

I want to print something at intervals.
But my code doesn't work, it throws an exception about deadlock.

Could you please help me with it? http://play.golang.org/p/pyEoXU-6Ee

```
func main() {
    c := time.Tick(1 * time.Minute)
    for now := range c {
        fmt.Printf("%v \n", now)
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works fine for me when I compile and run it locally. The play.golang.org has some strict rules for code that can run there. Infinite loops tend not to be among those allowed. try putting your code in a file and then using go run main.go to test it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have try it locally, and it does work.

Comment: By the way, I've found someone had improved my post - I mean the English grammars. And I'm really glad about this. So, thank you all who helped me with both Go programming and English grammars.

Comment: Can you please mark this answered? Thanks. (I've added an answer below, since I think you need an answer before you can mark it answered!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play.golang.org has some strict rules to protect it. If you run this locally, it works.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work in the https://play.golang.org/ is because `time.Tick(...)` is a dirty function, which is only safe to be used in an infinite loop that ends with the app (or other use cases where you don't mind leaking memory). As per Golang documentation:

> Tick is a convenience wrapper for NewTicker providing access to the ticking channel only. While Tick is useful for clients that have no need to shut down the Ticker, be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks". Unlike NewTicker, Tick will return nil if d <= 0.

So generally it's better to use `time.NewTicker(...)` instead. See example at: https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-NewTicker

Answer (score -2):

You can try [this instead](https://gobyexample.com/tickers):

```
package main

import "time"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1500)
    ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Ticker stopped")
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/FFDKMuR8_e